# Fudge into Australia

Tags: legal, australia, food-and-drink

Can I take fudge that has been produced in Guernsey (Channel Islands) into Australia together with my personal luggage?

Answer (score 4):

When you arrive you MUST declare all the food you are carrying. The Australian officials will then either confiscate it or let it in. (I think you can also arrange to ship it home or leave it at the airport for you to take home when you go.) You will only get into trouble if you try to sneak something in without declaring it. They have sniffer dogs and other ways of knowing what you're carrying. So if the fudge is bought and you're on your way, just tell them about it on arrival and get a decision made there.

Now, if you're trying to decide whether to buy it, or if you have time to eat it rather than see it confiscated, you need to check out [the Australian government web page](http://www.daff.gov.au/biosecurity/travel/cant-take) on what you can bring in. It list things you must declare, but that may be returned to you (that is, not confiscated). Your fudge absolutely must be declared. It seems, though, that it explicitly will be allowed in, according to [another government page](http://www.daff.gov.au/biosecurity/travel/cant-bring-form/australian_biosecurity):

> Confectionery (excluding Indian milk-based desserts and sweets) is allowed into Australia. Confectionery includes chocolate, **fudge**, toffees, boiled sweets, peppermints, marshmallows and liquorice etc. It does not include liquid dairy desserts, spreads or drinks, which are covered under the Dairy items heading.

[emphasis mine]. But remember, being allowed doesn't mean don't declare it. It means declare it, let them look at it, and thank them when they allow you to keep it.

Comment: You do NOT need to declare all food.  Only certain foods need to be declared, and these are detailed on the incoming passenger card.  One of the categories that needs to be declared is "dairy", so it would still be recommended to declare fudge - but realistically they will let it through as Kate has said.

Comment: The first link tells you what food you must declare. That includes all fresh, dried, or frozen fruits or vegetables, all fresh or powdered dairy products, all grains, all meat including dried, smoked, salted and frozen, and all commercially prepared food whether raw or cooked. I find that indistinguishable from "all food", myself.

Comment: Customs and quarantine updated their declaration cards and process in the last year or so.  Previously you did need to declare all food.  Now it's more limited.

Comment: The current declaration cards can be found at https://www.immi.gov.au/managing-australias-borders/border-security/travel/passenger-cards/samples.htm - they list a number of types of food that must be declared, but the generic "Any foods" that used to be on them was removed several years ago.